# Which platform is used in companies now-a-days to implement mobile applications?

Tags: mobile

Basically i would like to know which platform is currently used to develop mobile applications i.e. J2ME etc etc...
Also any new ideas on mobile applications would be quite helpful.

Comment: For what platform, that is, what mobile brand? You develop differently for the iPhone, Android, Blackberry or Symbian. Unless you're looking for something that will work (natively) in every mobile... which I am sad to report, but there's no magic bullet.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, the approach is to go for a website, if possible, and adapt it to each phone using a 'device detection layer'. We use [DeviceAtlas](http://www.deviceatlas.com/).

If you want to write native applications for each phone, then you need to do it in each of the native languages (and there are a lot).

- Symbian/Java: Greatest 'penetration'
- iPhone/iPod Touch: Latest trend, objective-c for this.
- Android: I think this is a variant of Java, and will be a very marginal component of the market for a long time, though maybe high among a certain type of techies.

Basically, you are going to need to profile your market, and determine the best approach. But as I said, in general, you'd prefer a website, and mostly, a website is all you need.

Answer (score 1):

There is a framework called [Rhodes](https://GitHub.Com/Rhomobile/Rhodes/) by [Rhomobile](http://Rhomobile.Com/) that allows development of native applications for all major smartphones. See [my answer](http://StackOverflow.Com/questions/698829/699133/#699133) to a similar question earlier this year.

Answer (score 0):

We are primarily targeting the iPhone, but don't always make an iPhone-specific application.  The web browser on the iPhone is good enough that a lot of our web apps just run there ok.  So many of the apps we're writing continue to be done using the same platforms we've always used.  We're a big institution so this runs the gamut from J2EE and .NET to Php and Ruby.

Mobile-only apps are developed in XCode (or web versions in DashCode).

Answer (score 0):

If you need to cover multiple mobile (esp. smartphone) platforms, Javascript (with HTML and CSS) may be the only way to go, despite all its limitations. You get under the radar of Apple's iPhone app vetting, it's the only way to target Pre, you can also cover Blackberry, Android, Windows Mobile, AND Nokia on a single codebase... unless the limitations are just TOO stifling for your specific purposes, it sure seems like *the* way to go!